# DateTime.format() unexpected behavior

Tags: apex, datetime, date, debug

Hi I am executing following code snippet and after 26/12/2015, date shifted to one year ahead of expected.

```
Date startDate = Date.parse('12/24/2015');
Date endDate = Date.parse('12/30/2015');

while(startDate <= endDate){
    Datetime localDateTime = startDate;
    startDate = startDate.addDays(1);
    System.debug('~~~~~localDateTime'+localDateTime);
    System.debug('~~~~~localDateTime'+localDateTime.format('MM/dd/YYYY'));
}
```

And following is the debug

```
19:14:17.040 (40027257)|EXECUTION_STARTED
19:14:17.040 (40036021)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
19:14:17.040 (40989828)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-24 00:00:00
19:14:17.041 (41059958)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/24/2015
19:14:17.041 (41128835)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-25 00:00:00
19:14:17.041 (41163269)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/25/2015
19:14:17.041 (41222037)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-26 00:00:00
19:14:17.041 (41254864)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/26/2015
19:14:17.041 (41312303)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-27 00:00:00
19:14:17.041 (41345356)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/27/2016
19:14:17.041 (41402820)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-28 00:00:00
19:14:17.041 (41434519)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/28/2016
19:14:17.041 (41493306)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-29 00:00:00
19:14:17.041 (41525359)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/29/2016
19:14:17.041 (41582636)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-30 00:00:00
19:14:17.041 (41613956)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/30/2016
```

Any Idea why it is happening ?

Thanks

Comment: It appears as though the year switch at the same time the year would have switched for the `endDateTime` when it would have gone to Jan 2nd 2016. It's as though the function couldn't handle checking the difference between the two and concluded you wanted the difference to be between dates in the same year. I know that doesn't explain it, but it's the day after Jan 1st of the `endDate` when it occurred is what seems significant to me. Perhaps there's more to your code than what you've posted that would add context?

Comment: @crmprogdev when you execute this code snippet only in developer console, you will find the same debug logs.

problem is just in the format method for dateTime.
But if you just do startDate.format(), it gives right answer.

I dont know what is the problem, but it seems bug to me.

Comment: I agree, this is weird, a simpler code fragment of: `Datetime dt1 = DateTime.newInstance(Date.newInstance(2015,12,30),Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
system.debug(Logginglevel.info,dt1.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));` yields `2016-12-30` ! in DC on na2 pod - I'd say a bug in `format(..)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually... the datetime format is right.

The capital **Y** merge field is the **WEEK YEAR** - which from the 27th December 2015 is IN 2016!

The lower case **y** merge field is the **CALENDAR YEAR** - which will be 2015 as expected.

Change your line to

```
System.debug('~~~~~localDateTime'+localDateTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy'));
```

and you will see your logs play properly.

Notes: The Datetime.Format uses the Java SimpleDateFormat library/technology, [documentation for which you can find here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: FYI this is because there are 52.14 weeks in a year... so the last 4 days fall "after" the last full week of the year. Happy Christmas everyone!

Comment: oh damn -- I should have thought of that.  +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

It appears there are a couple of things going on with your code. First, note that you're making the conversion to `DateTime` BEFORE you do apply the `addDays()` method. Next, note that you're not applying a complete date-time string for what you want to retrieve, instead only a date format string. Here's what I modified your code to and the results I obtained when I did.

```
Date startDate = Date.parse('12/24/2015');
Date endDate = Date.parse('12/30/2015');

while(startDate <= endDate){
    startDate = startDate.addDays(1);
    Datetime localDateTime = startDate;
    System.debug('~~~~~localDateTime'+localDateTime);
    System.debug('~~~~~localDateTime'+localDateTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'America/New_York'));
}
```

In doing the above, I don't get the change in years as you did. Instead, my results stop on 12/30/15 as expected. Perhaps using the `Date` class instead of the `DateTime` class would be a better choice for your purposes to obtain the results you're looking for.

```
12:27:20.033 (33312354)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
12:27:20.034 (34356431)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-25 00:00:00
12:27:20.034 (34455201)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/24/2015 19:00:00
12:27:20.034 (34575676)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-26 00:00:00
12:27:20.034 (34647444)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/25/2015 19:00:00
12:27:20.034 (34757811)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-27 00:00:00
12:27:20.034 (34825554)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/26/2015 19:00:00
12:27:20.034 (34934603)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-28 00:00:00
12:27:20.035 (35007963)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/27/2015 19:00:00
12:27:20.035 (35119893)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-29 00:00:00
12:27:20.035 (35187075)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/28/2015 19:00:00
12:27:20.035 (35296782)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-30 00:00:00
12:27:20.035 (35362918)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/29/2015 19:00:00
12:27:20.035 (35470083)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime2015-12-31 00:00:00
12:27:20.035 (35535528)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|~~~~~localDateTime12/30/2015 19:00:00
```

Edited to add, I just noticed the last debug log entry shows 12/31 vs 12/30. Adding the additional day would be expected in a `while loop` since *unlike* a `for loop`, it would go through one additional loop *while* the value is equal to 12/30/15, thus adding an additional day which would display as 12/31 in the local time format. Why it didn't get it exactly right, isn't clear to me, but it seems consistent. One appears to be displaying in GMT and the other in EST. I ran this both as Anonymous Apex from Eclipse and also from the Console in another org where I obtained the same results.

Comment: The bit you missed was the fact that you wrote "yyyy" instead of "YYYY". Case sensitivity matters.

Comment: @sfdcfox LOL! As usual, Apex is not case sensitive except when it is! Nice catch! But, I suspect this is a Java date-time method syntax issue and totally unrelated to Apex. ;) Oh, I now see Simon's answer confirming my suspicions.